# Period of a particular Cycle for a Bessel Function

Tags: calculus, limits, integers, bessel-functions, almost-periodic-functions

The Bessel Function of the First Kind $J_a(x)$, and the Bessel Function of the Second Kind $Y_a(x)$, at least when $a$, is an integer or half integer are cyclical, as their values go from positive to negative and from negative to positive an infinite number of times as $x$ increases.  They are not periodic however as the period length, in which $J_a(x)$ or $Y_a(x)$ are positive, or in which $J_a(x)$ or $Y_a(x)$ are negative is not the same for every cycle.  For the nth cycle of $J_a(x)$ or $Y_a(x)$, in which n is an integer, is there a formula for the period length of that cycle?

Comment: Look at the zeros of the two functions. Each "period length" is the difference of two consecutive zeros.

Comment: @Somos I understand that the "period length" is the difference between two consecutive zeros, but is there a formula for calculating the difference between two X-Values, in which the function has a value of $0$ that is more efficient than approximating the difference between two consecutive zeros by looking at a bunch of values and subtracting X-Values for which the function is very close to $0$?

Comment: For $a = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, $J_a(x)$ are actually decaying sinusoids for which the zeros are periodic (except at perhaps $x=0$).

Comment: Did you look at the [DLMF Chapter 10](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21#vi) entry for zeros?